# Spring Sec SAML Samples 2.0.0.M17: How to add custom SAML attribute statement to SAML response?

Tags: spring-saml

The samples ...

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/tree/develop/samples/boot

... work nicely. Thanks a lot.

I use: 2.0.0.M17

Derived from the samples, got a working Identity Provider (IP) up-and-running almost according to my basic needs (Spring Sec SAML Extension ).
I referred to the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/2.0.x-SNAPSHOT/

Sidenotes:

- The Service Provider (SP) side is not implemented with the help of Spring Security
- My IP implementation is primarily for testing purposes, similar to [Mujina](https://github.com/OpenConext/Mujina)
  and also to give a working design-by-contract example.

I lack the following information:

- How can I add a custom SAML attribute statement on the IP side?
- What declaration exactly determines, that a custom SAML attribute statement is to be provided by the IP, if there is any?
- Where is it intended to programatically fill the custom SAML attribute statement? I cannot find a class named `SAMLUserDetailsService` as it used to be, according to the documentation, which I do not expect to be updated yet.
- Would you recommend to modify the samples for my purpose, or is it to still to much work in progress to be used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is class named `MetadataGenerator.java` having method `getNameIDFormat` and this `interface NameIDFormat extends SAMLObject` can help. I am not using Spring Boot 2 but 1.x but Saml module has not changed much.